# How to get list of channels that i joined in telethon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, telegram, telethon

I want to make a script that shows the channels that i joined and then leave all of it
with this example:

```
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import LeaveChannelRequest
await client(LeaveChannelRequest(input_channel))
```

Comment: Question is unclear please explain more

Comment: Really simple a user joined many channels and get too many channels error from a telethon script well need a script to leave all of them first get a list of all channels that he/she joined and second leave all of it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to leave all the channels you're in, you have to fetch all the channels from the dialogs list and then just delete them. Here is a snippet.

```
async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
    if not dialog.is_group and dialog.is_channel:
        await dialog.delete()
```

Comment: For some reason, the client.iter_dialogs() is not retrieving any results! It's just stucked forever

Comment: try `await client.get_dialogs()`